# ListView scroll freezes when item is added in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

In my Xamarin Forms app I have a chat page with a ListView listing the chat items.

This is the chat page viewmodel:

```cs
public class IndexViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model.Chat> Items { get; set; }
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }

    public IndexViewModel()
    {

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Model.Chat>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command( () => ReadTheList());

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<RootPage, Model.Chat>(this, "NewMessage", (obj, item) =>
        {
            var chat = item as Model.Chat; // Inspecting this as a local variable during debugging looks fine
            // when an item is added like this the app freezes
            Items.Add(chat);
        });
    }

    void ReadTheList()
    {
        var items = repo.ChatList();
        Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            // when an item is added like this, all is fine
            Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Whenever a new chat message arrives I want to scroll down to the last message (the newly added message). So I have added this delegate in my View:

```cs
viewModel.Items.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => 
{
    if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0) return;
    Debug.WriteLine("I can always see this when a chat item is added to the collection");
    chatList.ScrollTo(viewModel.Items.Last(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);  // this is where the freeze happens
};
```

The last line of the delegate works fine when I add a list of items from local storage and the list scrolls to the bottom, but it freezes up my app when a newly received Chat item is added via a MessagingCenter subscription. This consistently happens when a new message arrives and the page is open and I am not interacting with anything on the page.

Can anyone help me debug this?

Comment: Have you tried just change `ScrollTo` call to  `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => chatList.ScrollTo(viewModel.Items.Last(), ScrollToPosition.End, false));`?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza good suggestion! That was exactly it. Can you please add this as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When handling heavy background process like dealing with list search, do it on a thread apart to avoid this kind of issue.

Change your `CllectionChanged` handler to this:

```
viewModel.Items.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => 
{
    if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0) return;
    Debug.WriteLine("I can always see this when a chat item is added to the collection");
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
        chatList.ScrollTo(viewModel.Items.Last(), ScrollToPosition.End, false));
};
```

Comment: Actually I _was_ running on a background thread. The problem was, I didn't keep it in mind that I was on a background thread and your suggestion was to dip back to the main UI thread to make UI changes. The new message call was triggered with `Task.Run(() => { MainPage.AddMessage(payload); });`